# 'module' object has no attribute 'analyse' when using jieba

Tags: pyspark

My pyspark job fail, and the error says that: 'module' object has no attribute 'analyse'. But I have already import jieba.analyse in the script. And similar script can run successfully in the vm locally. Not sure why the job fail.

part of my code is as follow:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
import jieba
from jieba import analyse
import pyspark
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext('local')
spark = SparkSession(sc)
text_file = sc.textFile("gs://xxx")
def process_uinfo(line):
    line = line.strip()
    line_arr = line.split('\t')
    (title, content) = line_arr
    l_title = jieba.analyse.extract_tags(title, topK=20, withWeight=True)
    return "\t".join([l_title, content])

out_rdd = text_file.map(process_uinfo)
```

And the error "'module' object has no attribute 'analyse'" occur in the following line:

```
l_title = jieba.analyse.extract_tags(title, topK=20, withWeight=True)
```

Comment: have you try without jieba like :  analyse.extract_tags(title, topK=20, withWeight=True)

Comment: It works! Thanks Rishikesh:)